# Redefining a Command in a Loop Over a Comma Separated List

Tags: loops, etoolbox

I want to redefine the `glossaries` package’s `\gls` commands to include an index entry and an optional argument for formatting the index entry. However, there are so many variants of this command (`\gls`, `\glspl`, `\glstext`, etc. as well as many of my own defined keys), that I want to loop this command through a comma separated list. I am trying to use `etoolbox` and its `\docsvlist` command to accomplish this. My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xargs}

\renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand%
        \csname oldgls#1\endcsname%
        \csname gls#1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\renewcommandx%
        \csname gls#1\endcsname%
        [2][2]%
        \csname oldgls#1\endcsname{##1}\index{##1##2}%
}
\docsvlist{pl,text}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\input{glossaryDefs} % A file defining myterm & anotherterm




\begin{document}

Some text \glspl{myterm}[|textbf] and some more text  \glstext{anotherterm}.

\printglossary
\printindex

\end{document}
```

However, I get the error `Missing \begin{document}.` I am pretty new to LaTeX and I suspect that there are probably a number of issues in this example. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to store the old macros and redefine them to also add `\index`. What's with the optional parameter given by `2`?

Comment: I hinted at the answer to this question in my MWE. The optional argument is supposed to customize the index entry. For example, `\glspl{myterm}[|textbf]` should be equivalent to `\oldglspl{myterm}\index{myterm|textbf}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `\do{pl}`, here's what happens:

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname oldglspl\endcsname\csname glspl\endcsname
\expandafter\renewcommandx\csname glspl\endcsname[2][2]%
  \csname oldglspl\endcsname{#1}\index{#1#2}
```

The first `\expandafter` expands `\csname`, so we get

```
\newcommand\oldglspl\csname glspl\endcsname
\expandafter\renewcommandx\csname glspl\endcsname[2][2]%
  \csname oldglspl\endcsname{#1}\index{#1#2}
```

and the consequence is a long string of errors, because this is just like doing

```
\newcommand\oldglspl{\csname}
```

which is certainly not what you want. For this application you need `\let`, not `\newcommand`.

Try with

```
\renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
  \csletcs{oldgls#1}{gls#1}%
  \expandafter\renewcommandx\csname gls#1\endcsname[2][2]{%
    \csname oldgls#1\endcsname{##1}\index{##1##2}%
  }%
}
```

The first instruction will do `\let\oldglspl\glspl`, so saving the meaning for usage in the redefinition of `\oldgspl`.

Note that `\csletcs` is provided by `etoolbox`; without it you should do

```
\expandafter\let\csname oldgls#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname gls#1\endcsname
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move \begin{document} to immediately after \makeindex.  However I could not do a complete compile as you did not provide the glossaryDefs.tex file.   MWE issue.

Comment: `\makeglossaries` should definitely be before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Fixed that, I should not answer questions after midnight as I confuse before and after:(